# why does the change event activates in a v-text-field when pressing enter, even if I didn't change anything?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

Why does the `@change` event activates in a `v-text-field` when pressing enter, even if I didn't change anything?

HTML

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-content>
      <v-container>
          <v-text-field
             @change="onChange"
             slot="input"
             label="Edit"
             v-model="test"
             single-line
          ></v-text-field>
      </v-container>
    </v-content>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

JS

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    test: 'test'
    //
  }),
  methods: {
    onChange () {
      console.log('changed')
    }
  }
})
```

For example,if I press enter without changing anything, then the onChange event shouldn't print "changed" because it's the same string ('test' in this example).

You can see this pen for example: https://codepen.io/jdash99/pen/aaEYLB?editors=1111

Comment: It was changed in recent versions I think. Better ask community if that was intentional. `input` normally emits change if you press enter but only if value has actually changed, `v-text-field` always emits it afaics. So ask them (if there is no changelog or an issue on github) if that was intentionally different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This definitely appears to be a bug in Vuetify, [introduced in `1.1.0-alpha.0`](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/commit/47c73e69f82ac4c553e8148e1737ae35315bdb47) to fix a different [bug](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/2982), where <kbd>ENTER</kbd> emitted no `change`-event at all. This new bug is now tracked in `vuetifyjs/vuetify` [Issue #5070](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/5070).

As a workaround, you'll have to check the value yourself in your `change`-event handler to determine whether an actual change occurred.